# Transparent image layering

Tags: java, image, swt

I'm working on a problem that requires me to have two 'layers'. Both of these layers will be superimposed onto a canvas which already has image data on it. What I need to accomplish is for the layers to be able to have transparent background and only the areas that I draw would be opaque. I've been messing around with it for some time now and keep running into dead ends. Each layer is an Java SWT image.

How can I create an SWT image that has a transparent background which I can then use a GC(Graphics Content) to draw onto? Furthermore, I then need to be able to draw this newly created SWT Image onto a canvas and not have it fill in the transparent background with an opaque background.

Descriptive image:
[image: Layering different images together]

Comment: Please specify what exactly your question is and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Heres a picture that describes it better than I can with words. http://imgur.com/QlB516Y

Comment: What about using a framework like [Draw2d](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/draw2d/) or [Zest](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/zest/index.php)?

Comment: I'm sort of nested into the swt framework. This is not a personal project, but rather a work problem. It would be overkill for the problem to implement draw2D, Zest or any drawing framework unless we rewrote all of the other drawing code to utilize it. To give a little background, the images I'm looking to layer is an expandable "legend" layer for a charting software. The "legend" overlays over the charts when desired and helps describe whats going on.

Comment: Did you have a look at the Eclipse tutorial about [image transparency](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-images/graphics-resources.html#Transparency)?

Comment: absolutely. Not exactly relevant to the problem at hand. Though I'm looking more at draw2d and gef

Comment: Well, it's hard to tell what's relevant and what not, since you didn't provide very much information about your problem. Please try to be as specific as possible and please add a real question to your post.

Comment: I've updated the question again to hopefully have a more explicit question. Please review.